# Python Link Two Arrays by Date

Tags: python

I have 2 arrays with the structure presented below which I want to concatenate in a certain way.

Is it possible to do the equivalent of a `vlookup` to go from the one array with the dates and 4 columns where the dates are matched?

Array 1:

`13/06/2016 10:34.      10.       20.`

---

Array 2:

`13/06/2017 10:34.       15.       18.`

---

The output should be:

`13/06/2017 10:34.       10.      20.    15.    18.`

...

...

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, in multiple ways. However, you first need to show us the attempts you have made on this problem. Also, the dates in your sample rows do not match exactly: they have the same days and months but different years. Do you want such dates to be considered identical? Are the dates "aligned" or sorted in the files or could they be mixed up? Also, just what do you mean by "arrays": nested lists, numpy arrays, or something else?

Comment: I agree with @Rory Daulton. Also, your input time is 10:34 but output is 10.34.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas

first = [
    ['2017-06-22', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['2017-02-11', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
    ['2014-05-30', 'g', 'h', 'i'],
    ['2015-02-11', 'j', 'k', 'l'],
]

second = [
    ['2017-01-01', 'm', 'n', 'o'],
    ['2014-02-02', 'p', 'q', 'r'],
    ['2017-06-22', 's', 't', 'u'],
]

df1, df2 = pandas.DataFrame(first), pandas.DataFrame(second)
df1, df2 = df1.set_index(0), df2.set_index(0)
result = pandas.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='inner')
```

If you want to include results which exists only in one table, drop the `join='inner'`.

Comment: Do you really want to answer a vague question where no work is shown? Also, the question seems to want to ignore the year in the dates, where your answer does not.